# How can I completely hide all questions with a certain tag?

Tags: support, feature-request, tags

Now that Windows 8 is out, my questions feed is overrun with Windows 8 questions. At this moment in time, 31 out of the 50 questions on the main page are about Windows 8.

I've got no experience with Windows 8 and I don't have that much of an intention to run it any time soon - so I cannot answer any of the questions on Windows 8.

Given that, I've added "Windows-8" to my list of ignored tags - but now my questions feed is overrun with 31 lightly greyed out Windows 8 questions.

Is there any way to completely hide all questions associated with the "Windows-8" tag? Or any tag for that matter?

Comment: +1 for asking a good [meta-tag:support] question. -1 for hiding [tag:windows-8].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the **hide ignored tags** checkbox in your preferences:

[image]

Comment: Heh. I've *never* seen that.

Comment: Blimey, neither have I and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have an ad blocker or any extension to customize stylesheets, you can add the following CSS rule:

```
.tagged-ignored { display:none; }
```

Or, for AdBlock rules:

```
##div.tagged-ignored
```

Comment: Good idea, only downside is that I'll only see 29 questions on the front page. It would be nice if they could be replaced by questions I may be able to help answer.